# Adding two classes with same name in iOS Project

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3

I am new to iOS development. Unlike android i don't have any packages in iOS. My requirement is that I want to add same class(class name) in multiple packages. In android I can create a package and in the package I can add a class and in another package I can add class with same name. But in iOS if I add a class which is already present in a project it gives an error stating "invalid-redeclaration of class".How can I add multiple classes with same name in iOS Project?

Comment: Please don't post duplicate questions. If you want to add more info to the original, click on its "edit" button and add the info to the original question.

Comment: Take a look here https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001281-1002226

Comment: I was the who asked that duplicate question. No one answered or commented on it. So i had to rephrase the question and ask it again

Comment: @ron27 thank you. Was able to solve it by generating classes using prefixes in swagger

Comment: @BharathReddy Welcome :). Was the link helpful? If so plz upvote the comment. Thank you.